# Strange behavior of UITableView when editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a editable `UITableView` (*with adding and deleting elements*) in my application.
It working strange.
While I have only one or two lines in it, everything is working perfect.
But if I add more items, I have an exception `'*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'`

I was unable to put breakpoints and handle it.
Maybe, somebody can help me?

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int plusRow = 0;
    if ([[self tableView] isEditing]) plusRow = 1;

    return [typeList count] + plusRow;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if ([indexPath row] > ([typeList count]-1)) {
        NSString * appendCellDescription = @"";

        if ([[self tableView] isEditing]) appendCellDescription = @"Add";

        [[cell textLabel] setText:appendCellDescription];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Accessing array: %d", [indexPath row]);
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[[typeList getObject:[indexPath row]] description]];
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Editing table view

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"Row: %d, count: %d", [indexPath row], [typeList count]);

    if (indexPath.row > [typeList count]-1) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
}

- (IBAction)btnModifyClick:(id)sender{
    if ([[self tableView] isEditing]) {
        [[self tableView] setEditing:FALSE animated:YES];
        [[self tableView] reloadData];
    } else {
        [[self tableView] setEditing:TRUE animated:YES];
        [[self tableView] reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `typeList`? I thought it's `NSArray`, but the call `[typeList getObject:[indexPath row]]` gives me doubts. Where is the call of `objectAtIndex:`, anyway?

Comment: It is not NSArray, it is a custom class, based on NSObject with method getObject... this is working ok.

Answer (score 0):

Generally This Error describe, When mistake in Array Index such like you array have 3 item and you tring to get/abstract  4th item from Array, at that time this type of Error generate.

Best way to find error use BreakPint. and Debug your project line by line. and find where your app. crush ?? i am sure that it cruse Around any array.

**EDIT:**

I thinks mistake in array name `typeList` check it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method with BreakPoint.

Answer (score 0):

`numberOfRowsInSection`is returning higher number of items count than the one fetched in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` datasource method, try debugging the returned value:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int plusRow = 0;
    if ([[self tableView] isEditing]) plusRow = 1;
    NSLog(@"%i",[typeList count] + plusRow);
    return [typeList count] + plusRow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way, to solve my problem.
I just changed "Sections" to 0 in XCode properties in storyboard TableView.
And now working ok.

Thanks to everyone to response!